# restrict ssh access for different users to different folders

Tags: ssh, web-server, web-hosting

I was looking up how to let multiple user ssh onto my server with the `authorized_keys` file.

I need to tweak it so that each user logs into a specific directory for each user (ie `joeBlah` can only see `~/folder34`).

I'm doing this so that I can have 3 different people working on different parts of a site and not letting them onto other parts of the site (ie `joeBlah` can work on `public_html/forum` and `buddy` on `~/public_html/contact`).

From what I can tell it comes down to editing the `command=` in `authorized_keys` but I can't find anything else on the topic.

Is there a way to specify each users `home` dir which is some arbitrary location on the server?

Comment: The `command` parameter runs the specified command when an SSH session is established - essentially disabling the shell. The home directory is typically just a starting place - users can still visit other directories. It sounds like you are looking to setup a chroot jail. You may look into [jailkit](http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/howtos_chroot_shell.html) as a starting point.

Comment: it sounds like the OP needs to just setup accounts for these users, and add their pubkey to the correct /home/user1/.ssh/authorized_keys file

Answer (score 0):

qwertymk,

The authorized_keys file is where public keys are placed for public key authentication. The file would not be the correct place to set users home directories.

Do those three users have their own account on the system or are you just adding separate public keys for joeblah and buddy while they log in with the same system account?

If each user has their own account on the system you can change their home directory with usermod.

Example:

```
usermod -d /path/to/public_html/forum joeblah
```

The command above would make it so when joeblah logged in he would be placed in /path/to/public_html/forum (assuming permissions are adequate).

Please provide more details about your setup if you want a more direct solution.